# Как поставить в ряд элементы в html и css

Tags: html, css, изображения, текст

только начал учиться работать с сайтами, не знаю что делать. Нужно поставить в ряд все эти элементы, ну у меня что-то не получается, да и вообще мне кажется что bootstrap криво работает, помогите пожалуйста) 
Вот  мой html код:

```css
/*Вот css код: */

.opisanie-img {
  margin-left: 300px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.opisanie-text {
  font-family: 'Francois One', sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.about_block {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #E4F1FE;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.about_server {
  margin: 30px auto;
}

.h3_stye {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #333333;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "RobotoLight";
  margin-left: 600px;
}


}
.about_img img,
.about_img_na img {
  width: 300%;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.about_text p,
.about_text_na p {
  font-family: "RobotoLight";
  font-size: 19px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="about_block" id="about">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="about_server">
            <h3 class="h3_stye">Игровые сервера Minecraft</h3>
            <div class="about_img">
              <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="images/minecraft-server-logo-template-10-by-andyhanne.jpg" alt="" width="450" height="450">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="about_text">
              <div class="col-md-8">
                <p>Наша администрация имеет большой опыт работы с серверами,в состав администрации нашего сервера допускаются только самые классифицированные и грамотные специалисты, на сервере присутствует интересные моды и плагины, которые не дадут вам
                  заскучать.</p>
                <p>Так-же у нас на сервере есть мини-игры такие как Bed-Wars,TNT-Run,Duels,Parkour и Sky-Wars, вскоре мы будем добавлять ещё мини игры, у нас так-же проходят ивенты и почти постоянно конкурсы в группе, заходи к нам не пожалеешь!.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Мне нужно что картинка и описание были в линию, аккуратно. А заголовок для описание над ним. Вот скрин:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: у вас ссылка на картинку относительная и в примере не работает. Кроме того, если пишете ,что вам нужно "в ряд", то это подразумевает ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНОЕ расположение. А у вас - в колонку. Уточните, пожалуйста, как именно вам надо.

Comment: Здравствуй, мне надо что бы после картинки шло описание в ряд ГОРИЗОНТАЛЬНО, а над этим всем заголовок

Comment: Если только начали, мой вам совет отложить всякие бутстрапы в ящик, сначала освойте верстку без лишних инструментов, потом уже беритесь за сторонние инструменты. Так у вас будет каша в голове

Answer (score 1):

.col должны находиться в .row и быть на одном уровне вложенности, по-хорошему.

Для вас подойдет структура:

```
.container
  .row
    .col-md-12
      Заголовок
  .row
    .col-md-4
      Первый блок
    .col-md-8
      Второй блок
```

Посмотрите как всё логично и понятно. Весь ваш блок это контейнер, внутри которого 2 строки - "заголовок на все 12 колонок" и "контент на 4 и 8 колонок."

Не вкладывайте .col в дивы about_img и about_text, вы так запутаете структуру. Сделайте два блока .col как в моем примере, внутри которых и создавайте свой контент с дивами и чем захочется. Визуально вы сразу будете видеть, что у вас есть строка, внутри которой 2 столбца на 4 и 8, внутри которых уже ваша верстка.

Comment: Не нужно делать нерабочие сниппеты.

Comment: Это не сниппет, а псевдокод в формате типа HAML. Отлично подходит для показа структуры, но знать надо.

Comment: Я немного запутался, новичок. Пользователь @And исправил мой вопрос, заменил сниппет на то что сейчас есть. И сообщил мне на будущее. Так что всё в порядке, спасибо.

Comment: @Инквизитор, думаю вам уже пояснили выше комментом, ну чтобы вы его увидели, я цитатну вас.

Answer (score 0):

Смысл HTML в том, чтобы максимально просто и читабельно представить структуру страницы. У вас непонятно зачем всё обернуто в 10 ненужных ничегонеделающих блоков. Надо стараться использовать как можно меньше элементов для достижения результата.

У вас это может выглядеть вот настолько коротко, с помощью обтекания `float`:

```css
.content {margin: auto; max-width: 1200px;} 
.title {font-family: "Comic Sans MS"; border-bottom: 2px solid orange;}
.descr {font-size: 18px;}
.left {float: left; margin-right: 10px; box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #333;}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <h2 class="title">Cheburashikus Sovietikus Vulgaris</h2>
  <p class="descr">
    <img class="left" src="https://gyazo.com/9a756bc92e60ee6e21a6d616d8211be8.png">
    Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст Описание и какой-то текст 
  </p>
</div>
```

*Класс `content` добавлен, чтобы основная статья на больших экранах не растянулась на весь экран, а оказалась в ценре. А в центр его отправляют ограничение по ширине, `margin: auto` и свойство `display: block` (у div оно присутствует по дефолту)

---

Но float - это не выравнивание, а обтекание. 

Именно для горизонтального выравнивания часто используется `display: flex`. Пример:

```css
.flex {display: flex; border: 1px solid #123;}
.moo {
  width: 25%; height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
  <div class="moo"></div>
</div>
```

Но в таком случае у каждого блока должен быть свой отдельный контент. А в вашем случае, когда есть текст и надо слева от него поставить небольшую картинку - легче будет через float. Т.к. если текст окажется длиннее картинки, будет заполнять и область под картинкой.

---

P.s. у тебя весь параграф идет одним предложением через запятые) Иногда полезно примерно прикидывать, как будет читаться этот текст и ставить точки там, где мысль заканчивается и должна быть небольшая пауза)